# After update today (19-1-2021) Evolution cannot connect to mailserver

Tags: networking, email, evolution

Since today's software update, Evolution is no longer able to connect to my mailserver.
I only get the following message:

> Could not connect to mail.myserver.nl: Invalid argument

quickly followed by:

> Could not connect to mail.myserver.nl: No route to host

I have a good connection, I can connect to myserver with a browser and my phone still has a good connection to the mailserver from the same network.

Software versions:

```
evolution/focal-updates,now 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
evolution/focal 3.36.1-2 amd64
Linux 5.8.0-38-generic #43~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 16:39:47 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update log:

```
Start-Date: 2021-01-19  09:14:53
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.177'
Upgrade: netplan.io:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3, 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.1, 7.0.0-4ubuntu0.2), qemu-system-x86:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), qemu-system-data:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), qemu-utils:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.1), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.3, 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2), qemu-kvm:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.7, 1.187.8), qemu-block-extra:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), qemu-system-common:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11), qemu-system-gui:amd64 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.10, 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.11)
End-Date: 2021-01-19  09:15:46

Start-Date: 2021-01-19  13:40:30
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.207'
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libnss-mymachines:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libudev1:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4), systemd-container:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3, 245.4-4ubuntu3.4)
End-Date: 2021-01-19  13:41:00

Start-Date: 2021-01-19  15:03:42
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.172'
Upgrade: dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.80-1.1ubuntu1, 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-19  15:03:45
```

I think the 13:40 update is causing the problem, because I have received mails until 12:40

If there is any information I could provide, please let me know. I could not find any problem notifications in /var/log or in the user directory.

Thanks for any help solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a server side issue. I had set evolution to use TLS on a dedicated port, when I change to STARTTLS it works again.

I will investigate what happened on the server side, but it is not an issue that was caused in updates of my workstation!